# Podman build cannot be stopped with CTRL+C in tmux

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux, podman

I noticed that CTRL+C doesn't work well with `podman build` when I'm running it from within tmux. When I hit CTRL+C I see a `^C` appearing in the terminal, but podman doesn't stop building the image. I think it stops later at some point, but it does not do that immediately.

Why is that?

//EDIT
I noticed that building with `docker build` allows me to stop with CSTL+C without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

the process with pid 1 that runs inside your pod intercepts signals such as `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` (from pressing CTRL+C).
It then sends a `SIGTERM` to all the processes under its management (anything running in the pod), so those processess have some time to terminate cleanly/gracefully.

If there are still processes around after a certain amount of time (10 seconds i believe), the pid 1 process will send a `SIGKILL` to all remaining processes, which kills them instantly; after that the pid 1 process itself can exit and let the entire pid namespace expire.

---

Basically, the short version is that the podman init process is trying to cleanly power things down instead of just ripping out the powercord.

If it bothers you, i imagine the 10 second delay is configurable somewhere (i've never looked). Another alternative may be to send a stronger signal.

Comment: Hmm, the thing is that the same build stops immediately after CTRL+C when using `docker` instead of `podman`.

Comment: Hmm, i suppose it's possible they don't use the same default settings for how to handle signals; generally podman does try hard to align with docker but there are still plenty of differences. Also, i'm not sure but i think the `build` submodule of `podman` may actually just be a wrapper around `buildah`(?) in which case that may use different defaults than the other 2 applications ; i'd try looking into like `--stop-timeout`, `--stop-signal`, `--sig-proxy` or maybe `stop_timeout` and `init` in *containers.conf*